# Java Apache Camel - Create a CamelContext object

Tags: java, apache-camel

The documentation in the "Getting Started" section says the following:
"1. Create a CamelContext object."
https://camel.apache.org/manual/book-getting-started.html#BookGettingStarted-CamelContext

I tried it like this:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonLibrary;

public class CamelDemoMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext camelContext = new CamelContext();
    }
}
```

But the language server in VS Code says the following:
"Cannot instantiate the type CamelContext"

And I also tried using `DefaultCamelContext` instead of `CamelContext` because I have seen it in some other project, but with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to create a `CamelContext` depending on how you want to launch Camel (Standalone, Spring Boot, Quarkus, CDI...).

Assuming that you want to launch Camel in standalone mode, you can create it using [`DefaultCamelContext`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-core-engine/3.0.0/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultCamelContext.html).

Like in the next basic example:

```
public final class CamelBasic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create a CamelContext
        try (CamelContext camel = new DefaultCamelContext()) {

            // add routes which can be inlined as anonymous inner class
            // (to keep all code in a single java file for this basic example)
            camel.addRoutes(createBasicRoute());

            // start is not blocking
            camel.start();

            // so run for 10 seconds
            Thread.sleep(10_000);
        }
    }

    static RouteBuilder createBasicRoute() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                from("timer:foo")
                        .log("Hello Camel");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/main/examples/basic